# Is Google Limiting indexed pages per website?

Tags: search-engine-indexing

hello i have up and running website for 3 months and for some reason i noticed that webmaster shows it indexing < 250.

i read some where that new domains with no history and backlinks have near zero DA and PR and thats the cause to low indexing limitation.
my domain had no history before.

by the way, google crawled all of my website. 400+ pages.
do u know the reasons for that?

Comment: There's no limit for new sites, however it does take a while for Google to add them to its index - several months in some cases. It also depends on if Google views your content as original, relevant, and not low in quality... You could try to use Fetch as Google on URLs that aren't indexed to see if there's any issues with them, and check your reports in Google Search Console to see if there's any crawl errors or other problems.

Comment: @dan i have very good originaly created content